# Django 1.9: NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a class based view which shows the data in template having **{% extends 'base.html' %}**.

My base file folder is in seperate folder called **products**

My App url

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
     url(r'^product_list/', views.ProductViewList.as_view(), name='ProductViewList'),
]
```

Template of class based view (product_list.html)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{{ object_list }}
{% endblock %}
```

My base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{% static 'css/starter-template.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

     {% include 'navbar.html' %}

        <div class="container">

          {% block content %}

          {% endblock %}

        </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js' %}></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i visit "http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/product_list/" following error pops up

[image]

My directory structure, My **base.html** is in **root directory**(templates) and **product_list.html** is in **products folder**

[image]

I **think** there could be problem with **{% extends 'base.html' %}**, But not sure how to sole the problem.......Any help is much appreciated

Here's my **first urls**...which **further redirects to my app url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^product/', include('products.urls')),
        url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    ]
```

Comment: try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_list/ `, since you defined `^product_list/'` in urls.py not `^product/product_list/'`

Comment: I already have base url [' url(r'^product/', include('products.urls')),']..........which is redirecting to products/urls.py

Comment: pls provide the full code of your base.html. How you get the above error? on putting the direct link on address bar? Did you click anything? did you specify something like `{% url 'name' %}` on ur code?

Comment: @AvinashRaj..I have added my full base.html as well as my main urls.py..which further goes to my app's urls.py...............I haven't specified {% url 'name' %} but have specified {% static  'link' %} in base.html

Comment: @AvinashRaj.........Thanks for your time........I found out that {% include 'navbar.html' %} was creating problem in base.html...........Any idea why it is creating a problem..........Is there any alternate way to include my navbar.html?

Comment: navbar.html probably includes a {% url %} tag that does not map to an app url pattern

Comment: @AviahLaor........please let me know how should I specify navbar.html in my APP URL.......This could be really helpful

Comment: @spidy What Aviah Laor meant is in *navbar.html* there is a `{% url 'home' %}` tag which is causing this error. Because there is no urlpattern named `home` in your *urls.py*. Either add a urlpattern named `home` in your urls or just remove that tag altogether from *navbar.html*.

Comment: Perfect..................Thanks it worked ..........cheers to all............

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a name to the view url that identify when you want to used in the template

```
from django.conf.urls import url
import myapplication.views

app_urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^article/(\d+)/$',views.article_detail,name='article-view-url'),
]
```

And this is how I use the url name in my html template

```
 {% for article in articles.object_list %}
        <article>
            <h3>
               <a href="{% url 'article-view-url' article.pk %}">{{ article.name }}</a>
            </h3>            
            <p>
                {{ article.desc }}
            </p>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
```